# Apparent circularity of the definition of mass

Tags: physical-organic-chemistry

I am not a chemistry student, so forgive me for the naïvety of the question. The atomic mass of an atom is defined relatively to the mass of 1/12 of the mass of an unbound neutral atom of carbon 12 in its nuclear ground state and at rest.

But here it seems that the mass of an atom is defined in terms of the mass of carbon itself! How then, is the mass of carbon 12 calculated? What even *is* mass? It seems obviously circular! If one says that the mass of carbon is calculated by adding the mass of a proton or some other quantity, how is *that* mass then defined?

A simple layman answer would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The atomic masses are somewhat circular with reference to carbon-12. It has a 200 year long history. We always need a reference to assign a number, right? These atomic masses are *relative* atomic masses. Mass itself is another story; but first read the Wikipedia entry on mass for starting. Mass, like charge is a property of matter.

Comment: Note that what you're describing is the *atomic mass*, not the *mass*. And the definition of atomic mass isn't circular, because the atomic mass of carbon-12 is defined to be exactly 12. Relating the atomic mass to an actual mass (in kg) would be a different thing altogether—this has to be physically measured, see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalton_(unit)

Comment: …and if you are asking about mass as physical quantity on general, note that kilogram is defined via fixed numerical value of the Planck constant and is not bound to carbon-12.

Answer (score 2):

This is not so different from the historic definition of mass of macroscopic objects.  You would have a set of weights kept by some town official, and these would define certain masses. During market in that town, those weights are the official ones. Merchants might have their own set of weights to sell their potatoes, but if there is conflict, you use the official weights.

Of course, a different town might have a different set of weights, making things a little bit fuzzy.

The good thing about using an atom as official standard is that the mass of a given isotope, different from a potato or a man-made weighing standard, is the same in every village.

Answer (score -2):

The mass of the carbon atom is not calculated. It is measured. Let me explain the principle of this operation.

To measure the mass of the carbon atom, a carbon sample has to be heated in a small box (as big as a match box) to such a high temperature that carbon is in a gaseous state. The whole is in a vacuum. Now there are two needles going one through the ceiling and the second through the floor of the box. The needles do not touch one another. An electric spark is then created between the needles. The spark is made of electrons getting out of one needle and jumping to the second needle. During their flight, these electrons are hitting some carbon atoms inside the box. This collision removes one electron from the hitted carbon atom, producing carbon ions $\ce{C^+}$.

Now the opposite (vertical) walls of the "matchbox" are made of metallic plates, one being charged positively and one negatively. So the positively charged carbon ions are moving in the direction of the negative plate. Most fall on this plate. But the plate is punched by a circular hole in its middle. So a small proportion of the $\ce{C^+}$ ions are just directed to the middle of the whole hole. They don't know to which part of the hole they have to go. Instead they just cross the center of the hole, specially if there is another plate parallel to the punched one, but being charged at a higher negative potential than the punched plate. This second plate attracts the flying ions stronger than the punched one. So the ions go through.

You may guess that the second plate is also punched in its middle just in front of the first hole. This produces a narrow jet of $\ce{C^+}$ ions, which are attracted by a third plate. And between the 2nd and the 3rd plates, an electric or a magnetic field is created that deflects the jet. But light ions are more deflected than heavier ones. So measuring the deflection allows you to calculate the mass of the ion, and of course the mass of the Carbon atom, which is defined as $12.000$.

The nature of the gas included in the original "matchbox" can be changed, and produces other ions. If by chance, another ion is deviated twice as much as the $\ce{C-12}$ atom, its mass will be defined as $6.000$. As a consequence, the mass of any present ion can be determined by this apparatus.

Comment: Are you describing a mass spectrometer?

Comment: Yes. it is a mass spectrometer. I have not told it, because the author of the question said that he is not a chemistry student.